# [PHP]How to create database-supported dynamic routes?

Tags: php, regex, routes, url-routing, altorouter

I'm coding a script.  I use altorouter as the route, but I want to add database support.
Why Database support?
1.My script support template system with altorouter. Route define route name.

Content DB structure

```
    cont_id int 11 Primary Key AI 
    cont_title varchar 150
    cont_desc varchar 255
    cont_body text
    cont_thumb int 11
    cont_addUser int 11
```

Content_tax DB structure

```
post_id int 11 
link_id int 11 
post_type varchar 60
```

Link DB structure

```
link_pid int 11 Primary Key 11 ai
link_url varchar 150
link_name varchar 100
```

Altorouter simple fast routing but maybe not dynamic with database

```
$router->map( 'GET|POST', '/users/[i:id]/', function( $id ) {
  $user = .....
  require __DIR__ . '/views/user/details.php';
});
```

How can we create a database-supported route system? or how can I make the altorouter route system with dynamic database support?
Note :**Please don't give negative points** I may not be able to explain it exactly.  Ask what you wonder. Help solve this problem.

Comment: do you mean , you want to access database from router? i don't understand your question

Comment: Similar. I want to store routes in database. $router->mal('get',$dbRoute->home,function($id){echo $id;}

Comment: your question is to unclear, please clarify, example you want to store route in your db? then for what ? whats the purpose

Comment: I'll try to rearrange the problem in the evening and understand the problem better.